# The table civicrm_activity includes an incorrect constraint

Tags: activities, activity

After updating CiviCRM I get the above warning. The Link added to the warning "Learn how to fix this" leads to this page https://lab.civicrm.org/-/snippets/85 which does not describe how I remove the incorrect constraint - at least I don't understand from this how to do it. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know how to manually run SQL queries in MySQL? You can use [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) or the [command line](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html) or some other control panel tool that might be installed in your hosting.

It's telling you to do it manually because the upgrade checked that you have a lot of activities in your database so it might take a long time to run. Optionally make a backup first, and then the query you want to run is

- `ALTER TABLE civicrm_activity DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_civicrm_activity_original_id;`
- `ALTER TABLE civicrm_activity ADD CONSTRAINT FK_civicrm_activity_original_id FOREIGN KEY (original_id) REFERENCES civicrm_activity (id) ON DELETE SET NULL;`

Then there are some optional things you can do depending on what strategy you want to use for handling deprecated CiviCase activity revisions. The easiest is run `DELETE FROM civicrm_activity WHERE is_current_revision = 0;`, but DON'T do that before running the above queries.

Comment: I've also updated the lab snippet a bit. I didn't notice how much the upgrade message wording was changed at the last minute.

Comment: Thank you for this fast and helpful response!